# asp.net Sendgrid Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(APIKey) return null value / Permission denied, wrong credentials

Tags: asp.net, webforms, sendgrid

I have an asp.net (webforms) application and I am using SendGrid to send scheduled emails.

The emails are not received and I get a 'Permission denied, wrong credentials' when I check the response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result

When I check the value of the Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(APIKey), it is returning a null value.

I am getting the SendGrid key from the webconfig, and it returns the value.
I have also tried by adding the APIKey string (SG...) directly in the code, and I had the same issue.

I assume I should be adding the sendgrid credentials somewhere, but where?

I am already using this ApiKey to send email from another application, and it works, however I am using smtpClient to send these emails.

This is the code that I am using:

```
    private async Task TestSendEmail(DateTime SendAt)
    {
        string APIKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendgridAPIKey"].ToString();

        var datetimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(SendAt, TimeSpan.Zero);
        var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(APIKey);
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        //var from = new EmailAddress(QueueEmailAdmin, "Example User");
        var from = new EmailAddress("FromEmail@gmail.com");
        var subject = "Test Email";
        var to = new EmailAddress("myemail@gmail.com", "Example User");
        var plainTextContent = "This is a test";
        var htmlContent = "<strong>This is a test</strong>";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        msg.SendAt = datetimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine(msg.Serialize());
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    }
```

Comment: I'm very confused. Don't you have the value (the API key) in web.config? What do you expect Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable() to do? Shouldn't you just pass your variable "APIKey" (on your first line) to the constructor of SendGridClient?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing. However if I look at the value var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(APIKey); it returns a null value. It seems that it is not passing the Environment information. I have updated the post, as I forgot to mention that the emails are not received, I assume it is because the value of the environment is not passed to the variable apiKey.

Comment: I don't think GetEnvironmentVariable() is doing what you think it's doing. It's for getting environment variables set globally on your computer. I assume you have the actual API key in your web.config, have you not? In that case, you should just forget the line  `var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(APIKey);` and use the result of `string APIKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendgridAPIKey"].ToString();` in the constructor of `var client = new SendGridClient(APIKey);`

Answer (score 1):

You must write like this...

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY", APIKey);

var apikey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY");

var client = new SendGridClient(apikey);
```